# Function analytic everywhere except at origin, and closed loop around origin is zero?

Tags: complex-analysis

I have this problem I cannot figure out:

**Problem:** True or false? Give a short proof or a counterexample:

If a function $f$ is analytic in $\mathbb{C} \setminus \left\{0\right\}$ and $$ \int_{C(0,1)} f(z) dz = 0,$$ then $f$ is analytic in the entire complex plane. Here $C(0,1)$ denotes a closed loop centered around $z = 0$ with radius $1$.

**Attempt:** I'm confused because it seems to me that these two conditions are contradictory. I know that if $\Gamma$ is any positively-oriented loop in the complex plane and $z_0$ is a point not on $\Gamma$, then \begin{align*} \int_{\Gamma} \frac{dz}{z-z_0} = 2 \pi i \end{align*} if $z_0$ lies in the interior of $\Gamma$, and otherwise the integral is zero, since then $\Gamma$ only encloses an analytic region. But here in this problem it is given that $f(z)$ is not analytic at $z_0 = 0$, and still the contour integral vanishes. Any ideas whether this statement is true or false, and why?

Comment: Your $2\pi i$ integral is for the specific function $f(z)=1/(z-z_0)$, but there are lots of other functions which fail to be analytic at a point.

Answer (score 2):

The function equal to $$f(z)=e^{\frac{1}{z}}-\frac{1}{z}$$ for $z \neq 0$ and to whatever you want for $z=0$ is a counterexample.

If you force $f$ to be continuous on $\mathbb C$, then $f$ is analytic on $\mathbb C$.

Answer (score 2):

The function $f(z) = 1/z^2$ will do nicely.